# Validate select dropdown. Only one option is correct to submit the form

Tags: php, laravel, validation

So I have a simple form with text box, drop down with 2 options and a submit button. I have a dropdown with two values - Google and Bing. If you choose Bing, I want it to throw an error. I have a similar thing made for the text box which accepts only letters. If you add a number to the input box it shows a regex error. How do I acquire this for my dropdown?

My blade file:

```
    <form action="{{route('redirectURL')}}" method="GET">

    <input {!!$errors->has('searchText') ? 'style="background-color: #faa"' : '' !!} type="text" 
    value=" 
   {{old('searchText')}}" name="searchText" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,30}" title="Vain [a-zA-Z0-9]{5,30}         
    hyväksytään"> <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>

    @error('searchText')
    <div style="background-color: lightgrey; width:230px;">
    {{$message}}
    </div>
    @enderror
    <select name="searchEngine">
    <option name="Google" value="http://www.google.com/search?q=" @if(old('searchEngine') ==         
    "http://www.google.com/search?q=") {{'selected'}} @endif >Google</option>
    <option name="Bing" value="http://www.bing.com/search?q=" @if(old('searchEngine') ==                 
    "http://www.bing.com/search?q=") {{'selected'}} @endif>Bing</option>
    </select>
    @error('Google')
    <div style="background-color: lightgrey; width:230px">
    {{$message}}
    </div>
    @enderror
```

And my Controller:

```
public function searchURL(){
$validator = request()->validate([
    'searchText'=> ['required','regex:/^[a-zA-Z]{5,30}$/'],
    'Google' => 'required'
],
    ['searchText.regex' => 'I accept only letters!',
    'Google.required' => 'Dont use Bing... use Google!'
    ]
);
```

The text box regex error displays it fine, but I can't figure out how to make a same type of error for the Bing option.

Comment: Opps, I found an error  `option name="Google"` option can't contain a `name` attribute. It just can take the value https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp `select` element is the parent of option, it can take `name` attribute

Comment: I tried to change your code to 
`if ($request->searchEngine == "http://www.bing.com/search?q=") {
  return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['engine', 'Dont use Bing... use Google!']);
}`

But it doesn't work either. Maybe I need to use some other technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select in html form works differently

```
<select name="engine">
   <option value="bing">bing</option>
</select>
```

in above code when you submit
data in request will be

```
engine = bing
```

so you have to put validation on  `'engine' key`.
in you code you have to put validation on `searchEngine`

// option one: 'in' takes a comma-separated list of acceptable values
`$rules = [ 'engine' => 'in:google', ];`

add this rule and check if it works change key value as your requirement

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-in

Comment: That explains why I have the error up on both of the options. But how can I write it out? 

`'searchEngine'=> 'required'`

How can I put Google in there specifically?

Comment: @DidzisZvaigzne i have updated ans check if it can help

Comment: Thanks for the update. So it is impossible to add it to my $validator variable? I have to add the rule?

Comment: @DidzisZvaigzne
`$validator = request()->validate([
    'searchText'=> ['required','regex:/^[a-zA-Z]{5,30}$/'],
    'searchEngine' => 'in:Google'
],`
try this if it works

Comment: The error shows up now and on the right occasion! Yay! Now the error shows up as: The selected search engine is invalid. Even though I put the error message as:
 `['searchEngine.required' => 'Bing doesnt work.']);`

Any ideas how to fix the message?

Comment: @DidzisZvaigzne change 'searchEngine.required' to 'searchEngine.in' this might work
and don't forget to give +1 :).